# MapStructs for classes with different data types

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am new to mapstructs, and I wanted to map these two class structures

Target classes:

```
@Data
class Student{
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;
    private List<Academic> academics;
}

@Data
class PersonalInfo{
   private String name;
   private String address;
}

@Data
class Academic{
   private String subject;
   private String score;
   private String grade;
}
```

and the DTO classes are as follows,
Source:

```
class StudentDTO{
    private PersonalDTO personal;
    private List<AcademicDTO> academics;
}

class PersonalDTO{
   private String name;
   private String address;
}

class AcademicDTO{
   private String subject;
   private Double score;
   private Long grade;
}
```

I was able to map PersonalDTO class to PersonalInfo but not AcademicDTO to Academic(as all the data types in Academic are String and AcademicDTO has Double and Long).

Can someone please help me create a **Student mapper** which maps PersonalDto to Personal and AcademicDto to Academic. Thanks.

Comment: Did you configure your mapper with `typeConversionPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR`? Because times29's answer shows it can work automatically. If all else fails you can add qualified mappings for the score and grade, where you explicitly perform the conversion.

Comment: thanks @RobSpoor that was the case i missed the typeConversionPolicy

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.
Did you maybe forget the setters on the DTOs?

#### POJOs

```java
@Data
@Builder
public class Academic {
    
    private String subject;
    private String score;
    private String grade;
    
}

@Data
@Builder
public class PersonalInfo {
    
    private String name;
    private String address;
    
}

@Data
@Builder
public class Academic {
    
    private String subject;
    private String score;
    private String grade;
    
}
```

#### DTOs

```java
@Value
public class StudentDTO {
    
    PersonalDTO personal;
    List<AcademicDTO> academics;
    
}

@Value
public class PersonalDTO {
    
    String name;
    String address;
    
}

@Value
public class AcademicDTO {
     
     String subject;
     Double score;
     Long grade;
     
}
```

#### Mapper

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface StudentMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "personal", source = "personalInfo")
    StudentDTO toDTO(Student student);

}
```

#### Mapper Test

```java
import org.assertj.core.api.recursive.comparison.RecursiveComparisonConfiguration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class StudentMapperTest {

    private final StudentMapper studentMapper = new StudentMapperImpl();

    @Test
    void toDTO() {
        // Arrange
        final Student student = Student.builder()
                .personalInfo(PersonalInfo.builder()
                        .name("John Doe")
                        .address("123 Main Street, New York, NY 10030")
                        .build())
                .academics(List.of(
                        Academic.builder()
                                .subject("Math")
                                .score("100")
                                .grade("1")
                                .build(),
                        Academic.builder()
                                .subject("Science")
                                .score("90")
                                .grade("2")
                                .build()
                ))
                .build();

        // Act
        final StudentDTO studentDTO = studentMapper.toDTO(student);

        // Assert
        assertThat(studentDTO.getPersonal()).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(student.getPersonalInfo());
        assertThat(studentDTO.getAcademics())
                .usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(RecursiveComparisonConfiguration.builder()
                        .withEqualsForFields((a, b) -> Double.parseDouble(a.toString()) == Double.parseDouble(b.toString()), "score")
                        .withEqualsForFields((a, b) -> Long.parseLong(a.toString()) == Long.parseLong(b.toString()), "grade")
                        .build())
                .isEqualTo(student.getAcademics());
    }
    
}
```

#### Generated Mapper Impl

```java
@Component
public class StudentMapperImpl implements StudentMapper {

    @Override
    public StudentDTO toDTO(Student student) {
        if ( student == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        PersonalDTO personal = null;
        List<AcademicDTO> academics = null;

        personal = personalInfoToPersonalDTO( student.getPersonalInfo() );
        academics = academicListToAcademicDTOList( student.getAcademics() );

        StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO( personal, academics );

        return studentDTO;
    }

    protected PersonalDTO personalInfoToPersonalDTO(PersonalInfo personalInfo) {
        if ( personalInfo == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String name = null;
        String address = null;

        name = personalInfo.getName();
        address = personalInfo.getAddress();

        PersonalDTO personalDTO = new PersonalDTO( name, address );

        return personalDTO;
    }

    protected AcademicDTO academicToAcademicDTO(Academic academic) {
        if ( academic == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String subject = null;
        Double score = null;
        Long grade = null;

        subject = academic.getSubject();
        if ( academic.getScore() != null ) {
            score = Double.parseDouble( academic.getScore() );
        }
        if ( academic.getGrade() != null ) {
            grade = Long.parseLong( academic.getGrade() );
        }

        AcademicDTO academicDTO = new AcademicDTO( subject, score, grade );

        return academicDTO;
    }

    protected List<AcademicDTO> academicListToAcademicDTOList(List<Academic> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<AcademicDTO> list1 = new ArrayList<AcademicDTO>( list.size() );
        for ( Academic academic : list ) {
            list1.add( academicToAcademicDTO( academic ) );
        }

        return list1;
    }
}
```